# Visual Studio 2012 install: ngen hangs/does nothing

Tags: installation, windows-7-x64, visual-studio-2012, ngen

I've been trying to get Visual Studio 2012 Professional RC installed (upgrading from VS 11 Beta on Windows 7 x64) and I'm finding that the installer seems to "hang" at seemingly arbitrary times.  I use quotes, because the installer UI is still completely responsive; it just seems to sit there and refuse to go any further.  What I have observed is the following:

- An instance of msiexec.exe (32-bit, running as SYSTEM) pins one of my 4 cores.
- 2 instances of vs_professional.exe appear to be running (both using my identity).  One of them (the main UI instance) is constantly using 1-2% CPU, presumably while it goes about its business to see if the progress bar has to be updated etc.; the other instance does not appear to use any CPU at all.
- An instance of ngen.exe appears to be sitting doing nothing i.e. no CPU usage.

When I run setup and specify the log file location, I can see the installer generate log files for all the components it successfully installs.  When it gets to the package that "hangs" (which is different every time I run the installer), the common denominator every time is that it has just made a call to ngen.exe to generate a native image during the install.  **This hang occurs regardless of whether I'm attempting to do an install, an uninstall or a repair**

I've tried leaving the machine to do its thing overnight, sometimes for up to 16 hours and when I come back it's still stuck at the same point.  If I cancel setup from the UI, I see a message in the UI saying "Stopping current session", but nothing appears to happen.  If I kill the ngen.exe process, I can see in the log file that the installer moves onto generating/uninstalling another native image, which again causes a hang.  If I kill the non-active vs_professional.exe after clicking cancel in the UI, installation ends successfully with an "X of Y components were installed/uninstalled successfully" message.

Any ideas/suggestions?  I'm at my wit's end trying to get this mess cleaned up!

Comment: You by any chance have Trend Micro AntiVirus installed/running?

Comment: Nope.  I do have Microsoft Security Essentials installed though.  Will try disabling it, running the install again and report back.

Comment: I have not had issues with MSE. Just TM's realtime filter.

Comment: Yeah I'm still seeing the same problems with MSE disabled, so it's not that.

Comment: I've got the same problem. I have also seen this behaviour before with various Visual Studio-related installers and update packages in 2010. If I kill ngen.exe's parent msiexec.exe I can get the setup to move on, but obviously I shouldn't need to do that and it's probably leaving something in an inconsistent state.

Comment: I have the same situation with VS2013

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation with the VS2012 Update 2.

I found that you can resume the suspended ngen processes and get through the install completely, but I did so by installing all the components individually (using the /layout param for the setup file).

Another note: If you look at the suspended ngen process and the command args it was started with, you can run ngen with the same args and it will execute successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I spent the better part of a day fighting this same problem. I had success by creating a new windows profile and running the install from there. I was using Windows 8 x64 (which made everything that much more frustrating)

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what steps I always do to fix almost issues related with windows installer (SQL ,VS ...)
Before go details you should know path of logs file when Windows save for easier and/or investigate by yourself :

Default is :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log
or C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log
we can see one or more than one folders here: 100 for SQL2008 ,110 for SQL2012 and 120 for SQL2014 ...
You should care about time/date folders was created .It's time you run setup.exe

Now go detail:

Almost issue I met is hangs / does nothing / disappear ... and cannot finish setup (hangs forever) --> you can see logs file and know why its hangs forever by yourself ,it's easy to know when you read logs :)

Step 1: Make sure your source setup is correct

Step 2: When you meet hangs / does nothing .. ,turn of programs and restart 01 time

Step 3 :Re-run setup  - If still hangs ,open task manager beside and NOTE with what is new programs " pop up" and NOT disappear 
(In my case it hangs at ExecuteStandardTimingsWorkflow and I saw Microsoft common language run time native compiler (ngen processes) pop up and NOT appear so I End task it manual and Windows keep running setup )

Step 4: Some time programs cannot delete /remove or run some component setup so you need help it.
Reading logs file and scroll end page ,you can see the last progress and if programs cannot do it you need help it .

Step 5: Taks manager and find windows installer ( msiexe processes) and some of them NOT responding and you need kill it by manual.

Step 6: Restart PC when it hangs 
Sometime programs need 01 restart to finish some task and it will continue automatic after restart .

It is what I always do and 99% case with install were fixed and run stably after then.
Hope this helps :)